# "LOAD DATA INFILE" gives problem when using several in sequence

Tags: php, mysql, csv, mariadb, load-data-infile

I have a rather large product feed which i split up in multiple csv files of 20k lines each.

```
feed-0.csv
feed-1.csv
etc
```

I load this csv into a temp table and export 3 new csv files which i will lateron load into seperate tables.

```
products.csv
attributes.csv
prices.csv
```

Above of course also contain 20k lines just like the (split) source, so far so good, all going well.

Another part of the script loads above 3 csv files into their respective tables, db.products , db.attributes and db.prices. When i select 1 file (be it feed-0.csv or feed-9.csv any split file will do) the database is updated with 20k rows in each respective table. Still no problem there.

Now i create a loop where i loop through the split csv files and add 20k rows to each table on each loop.

This works well until i hit the 3rd loop. then i will get mismatching numbers in the database. e.g.

```
db.products  - 57569 rows
db.attributes - 58661 rows
db.prices   - 52254 rows
```

So while on the previous all was 40k, now i have mismatching numbers. 
I have checked the  products.csv, attributes.csv and prices.csv on each loop, and these have each the 20k as they should have.

I have tried with random split feeds, e.g. feed-1.csv, feed-5.csv, feed-7.csv  or feed-1.csv, feed-8.csv and feed-3.csv. So i changed the files, i changed the order, but each time on the 3rd  and further loops i get this problem.

I tried to import split files from different feeds too, but each time 3rd loop i get incorrect numbers. The source files should be good. When i run just 1 or 2 files in any sequence the results are goods.

I suspect that i am hitting some limitation somewhere. I thought it might be a innodb buffer issue, so i restarted the server, but the issue remains. (innodb buffer around 25% after the 3rd loop)

I am using MariaDB 10.1.38, PHP Version 7.3.3, innodb buffer size 500mb

Any pointers in what direction i have to search for a solution would be welcome!

Comment: Is there any reason after importing the original files that you don't want to create the permanent data direct from these tables.  Unloading the data and then reloading it in itself seems like a long winded route.

Comment: Do these files _explicitly_ define their ID column, or are you relying on auto-increment to regenerate them without violating FK constraints? [spoiler: it won't] Maybe show us your code.

Comment: Does the problem only occur with large files? If you do 3 files with 10 lines each, does it also fail on the 3rd file?

Comment: @NigelRen The issue is that i cannot load data directly in the main table since i need to do mapping of the columns, as the layout/column sequence varies per source feed.

Comment: @barmar it seems to go well until i reach about 50k, then the problems arise.

Comment: @Sammitch thanks for the feedback, i am actually very new to MySql and Databases in general, so i have to search some background on your feedback. Showing the code is a bit complicated as the query includes variables which come from other table to handle setting of the columns for the LOAD DATA INFILE query.

Comment: I have solved the mystery, above 50k it was showing a tilde in front of the number of rows, so e.g. ~54,554 rows. After a further search on Google, i learned that it means that it is an approx rumber which can differ up to 40% from the actual number. 

So i ran a count on each table, and the numbers are matching, even though they show different number.

Comment: From the documentation: **`SHOW TABLE STATUS` does not give accurate statistics on InnoDB tables except for the physical size reserved by the table. The row count is only a rough estimate used in SQL optimization.**